# Web Application often Error until changing WebConfig?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

i have a question in general:

I have a WebApp in ASP.net. Entry point is an HTML-Site with Login-Form this is calling a Login.aspx for validating users.

I have often the Situation, that Login.aspx redirects to custom error page. It is no Error in the code. When i make a change in the WebConfig on the Server, the login is running again. So i think it is a question of IIS or ASP-Compiler configuration or so.

Has anyone experience with a similar behavior? It is not a Code problem, app is running as expective. Every few Days comes this situation and i have to make the web-config a new change-timestamp too make IIS reload it.

Have no ideas, how i can fix this?!

Please help!!!

Comment: No one can help if you don't describe clearly what is "that Login.aspx redirects to custom error page". Screen shots and/or IIS log entries are at least.

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see what caused Login.aspx to redirect to a custom error page, and when you solved this problem, what changes did you make to web.config?